# Material UI Grid set horizontal line instead of responsiveness

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Is there a way for me to disable responsiveness on the material UI grid as in the example below? This is achievable easily with a basic HTML table and when it scales down it adds a horizontal line to scroll, material UI grid is responsive and makes an effect in the example below

[image]

Is there a way to make "wanted" results on mobile with a material UI grid? the reason I chose material UI grid instead of HTML table is because of additional components that carry div element and react doesn't like combining table and div

Without sharing too much detail current set of a grid is the following:

```
<div>

<Grid container>
    <Grid item xs={5}>Event</Grid>
    <Grid item xs={2}>Sold</Grid>
    <Grid item xs={2}>Gross</Grid>
    <Grid item xs={2}>Status</Grid>
    <Grid item xs={1}>More</Grid>
</Grid>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this `<Grid container></Grid>`

```
<Grid container>
      <Grid container Event xs={5}>
        <FormRow /> 
      </Grid>
      <Grid container Sold xs={2}>
        <FormRow /> 
      </Grid>
      <Grid container Gross xs={2}>
        <FormRow /> 
      </Grid>
      <Grid container Status xs={2}>
        <FormRow /> 
      </Grid>  
    <Grid container More xs={1}>
        <FormRow /> 
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
```